# SAS: Conditionally create new data set if observation in a column is >= specified value

Tags: sas

I want to only create a new data set when any value in the 'count' column of a temp data set is greater than or equal to 10.

```
    Name  Fruit  Count        Name  Fruit  Count
    Jon   Apple    2          Tim   Apple    4
    Jon   Pear     1          Tim   Pear     7
    Jon   Kiwi     9          Tim   Kiwi     10
```

So reading over the first table would ignore it and reading over the second would create a new data set named 'Tim'. I'm using a PROC MEANS to calculate certain values and write to a temp data set. From there I want to read over that and if the conditions are met, create the new data set.

Comment: what do you want in your new dataset?

Comment: @user3645882 everything from the temp set.  Name Fruit and Count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data temp;
input name $ fruit $ count;
datalines;
Jon   Apple    2          
Jon   Pear     1          
Jon   Kiwi     9          
Tim   Apple    4 
Tim   Pear     7 
Tim   Kiwi     10
;
run;
/*
2 options:
all obs for Tim
*/

data _NULL_;
    set temp;
    file "MyPath\NewDataset.sas";
    if count>=10 then do;
        put "data " name ";";
        put "   set temp(where=(name='" name +(-1) "'));";   
        put "run;";
    end;
run;

/* only the obs with count>=10 */
data _NULL_;
    set temp;
    file "MyPath\NewDataset.sas";
    if count>=10 then do;
        put "data " name ";";
        put "   set temp;";   
        put "   if _N_=" _N_ ";";                            
        put "run;";
    end;
run;

%include "MyPath\NewDataset.sas";
```

Comment: The first option works the way I need it to. Thank you.

Comment: Just one note: if Tim had more than one fruit with count>=10 in the pgm you would get twice the same datastep that would then be executed twice, if your data is small it would not matter much, if big you may have to do some extra work to avoid wasting time

Comment: `proc sql; create table write as select distinct name from temp where count>=10; quit; data _NULL_; set write; file "MyPath\NewDataset.sas"; put "data " name ";"; put " set temp(where=(name='" name +(-1) "'));"; put "run;"; run;`